# How to "clip" similar emails and import only part of them in Google Sheets

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use a script to import the body of emails to a sheet.

This is the part of the script that imports the body of emails to a sheet

```
  var newReceipts = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < foundThreads.length; i++) {
    var messages = foundThreads[i].getMessages();
    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
      var subject = messages[m].getSubject(); //subject field
      var body = messages[m].getPlainBody(); //body field
      var from = messages[m].getFrom(); //from field
      newReceipts.push([subject,body,from]);
```

A sample text (body) would be:

```
some text I need to keep,  
more text I need....  

Did you know that:  

bla bla bla and more and more I DON'T need
```

Another email could be:

```
Our meeting will take place on Monday

Did you know that:  
You cannot be late?
```

A third email could be:

```
There is great strain in our group.
The following people please report to the human resources department.
John
Mary
Paul

Did you know that:
A raise is coming next month?
Pay increases tend to vary based on inflation, location, sector, and job performance.
Most employers give their employees an average increase of 3% per year.
Consistent job switching may have an impact on the rate at which your salary increases.
```

So, there is always a top part, followed by the constant `Did you know that:`, followed by a bottom part.

**I only need to keep the top part of the email** before the `Did you know that:`

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I would like to clip/stop the body up to Did you know that: I only need to keep the top part of the email`. When your sample of `A sample text (body) would be:` is used, what result do you want to retrieve?

Comment: I get the whole email. But. I only want the top part of the emails, leaving out the bottom part that starts with `Did you know that`. Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const check = "Did you know that";
const sample1 = `some text I need to keep,  
more text I need....  

Did you know that:  

bla bla bla and more and more I DON'T need`;
const sample2 = `Our meeting will take place on Monday

Did you know that:  
You cannot be late?`;
const sample3 = `There is great strain in our group.
The following people please report to the human resources department.
John
Mary
Paul

Did you know that:
A raise is coming next month?
Pay increases tend to vary based on inflation, location, sector, and job performance.
Most employers give their employees an average increase of 3% per year.
Consistent job switching may have an impact on the rate at which your salary increases.`;
const values = [sample1, sample2, sample3];
const res = values.map(e => e.includes(check) ? e.split(check)[0].trim() : "");
console.log(res)
```

- When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

  ```
    [
      "some text I need to keep,  \nmore text I need....",
      "Our meeting will take place on Monday",
      "There is great strain in our group.\nThe following people please report to the human resources department.\nJohn\nMary\nPaul"
    ]
  ```
- When the value of `check` is not included in the text, `""` is returned.
- When your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

  ```
    var newReceipts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < foundThreads.length; i++) {
      var messages = foundThreads[i].getMessages();
      for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
        var subject = messages[m].getSubject(); //subject field
        var body = messages[m].getPlainBody(); //body field

        // --- Added
        const check = "Did you know that";
        if (body.includes(check)) {
          body = body.split(check)[0].trim();
        }
        // ---

        var from = messages[m].getFrom(); //from field
        newReceipts.push([subject,body,from]);
  ```

#### References:

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I think it is the `getPlainBody()` that should be trimmed. The only constant I have is `Did you know that:`. Everything else is different in each email. I use the script to import all incoming emails from a specific sender.  So. Will your script trim every email and **keep only all text over the constant** `Did you know that:`?

Comment: @marikamitsos Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `I think it is the getPlainBody() that should be trimmed.` and `So. Will your script trim every email and keep only all text over the constant Did you know that:?`. Can I ask you about the detail of them? By the way, I have only the information in your question. The reason that I cannot imagine your other emails is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So, can you provide more sample values for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: @marikamitsos Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current issue, for example, when `if (sample.includes(check)) {}` is used like `if (sample.includes(check)) { const res1 = sample.split(check)[0].trim(); console.log(res1); }`, is that related to your current issue? By this, the text including the value of `check` is used.

Comment: I have updated my question with more examples. Does that help?

Comment: @marikamitsos Thank you for replying. And, those sample input values are from `var body = messages[m].getPlainBody()`. In your 3 sample input texts, you want to `some text I need to keep,  \nmore text I need....`, `Our meeting will take place on Monday` and `There is great strain in our group.\nThe following people please report to the human resources department.\nJohn\nMary\nPaul`, respectively. My understanding is correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @marikamitsos Thank you for replying. From your reply, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247320/discussion-between-marikamitsos-and-tanaike).

Comment: It is perfect now. Thank you @Tanaike

Comment: A question as part of knowledge. You used this simple `body = body.split(check)[0].trim()` to return the bottom part. How could one return **the top part** of the email?

Comment: @marikamitsos Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `You used this simple body = body.split(check)[0].trim() to return the bottom part.`, in this case, the top part upon `check` is retrieved because of `[0]`. When you want to retrieve the bottom part, please use `[1]`.